# Set opacity for some cell of the table

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iPhone application I have a view with table view on it. I need to set opacity for some cell of the table. I have tried:

```
UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
                backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                tableViewCell.backgroundView = backView;
                tableViewCell.backgroundView.alpha = 0.6f;
```

But I still not see the background of the view under table. How can I fix this?

Comment: you can add a transparent view for the area in which you want to set alpha. when ever you want to set alpha for that, set the white color and alpha accordingly to that view.

Answer (score 0):

Set `backView.layer.opacity = 0.6f`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the table view's opacity also to `0.6f`

Answer (score 0):

Where did you set the background alpha? Did you try setting it in  `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method ?